# How To Use Javascript to Get Field Value From Another List?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

Salvete!  How do I use javascript to fetch a value from a custom list that is not loaded in the browser?

[This post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29295/cannot-get-field-value-of-list-item-through-javascript) seems relevant, but it fetches values from a list that is loaded.

From that post, I have created this, but I can't get it to show any alerts or log anything in the console.  I can't say I understand exactly what is going on, however - delegates are shaky ground for me, and I am just learning the sp functions.

```
spload("getFields('Retreats', 'Capacity')");   //this is how I am calling the function

function spload(whatfunction){    //waits until sharepoint is ready
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push(whatfunction);
}

function getFields(listName, whatcolumn){
  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = context.get_web();
  var lists = web.get_lists();
  //var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
  //var list = lists.getById(listId);
  var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listName); 
  var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();  //<-- IS THIS RIGHT?  If my list is not loaded, how can there be any selected items?

  this.items = [];
  for (var i in selectedItems) {
    var id = selectedItems[i].id;
    var item = list.getItemById(id);
    items.push(item);
    context.load(item, whatcolumn);
  }
  context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, getAndShowTitle),
    Function.createDelegate(this, showError));
}
function getAndShowTitle() {
    for (var item in items) {
        console.log(item.get_item(whatcolumn));
        alert(item.get_item(whatcolumn));
    }
}
function showError(sender, args) {
  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

**[update]**

Now, notice this line:

```
 var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
```

If the list isn't loaded, how can there be any selected item?

Comment: your delay function is not right. The ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded function will wait until the SP.js file(the client object model) is loaded before firing.  The _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames function is a holdover from SP2007 and will not work with client object model code.

Comment: I didn't realize you commented here!  I tried putting `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(whatfunction, "sp.js");` in place of my own within my spload function, ` _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push(whatfunction);`, but my codes don't fire.

Comment: Okay, I'm back to this: I've got the function firing, but can't get the listname right.  My list is in the same site as the one from whence I am trying to fetch data, but it says, `List '/teamsite/mylist' does not exist at site.  How should I specify the list name?

Comment: edit your post to show your code as you have it now. Your getListByTitle() should get the title of the list, not the url or siteName/listName, just the list title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you linked should do the trick with one small tweak:

replace this line:

```
var list = lists.getById(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList());
```

with this:

```
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
```

...where listName is the name of your list.

You also need to actually call your getFields function, so put this at the top:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getFields, "sp.js");
```

Comment: Okay, I posted my new version based on your edit.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: ...and I edited my answer as well.  You're welcome!

Comment: I actually was using my own version of a delay, which I added to my code above.  My spload function will call an alert without issue.  Is `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` a better approach?

Comment: yes, because it's made for the client object model.  Your approach will work for init.js and the other 2007-era js files, but NOT SP.js, which is the client OM.

Comment: But even though I am using 2010, if I use the 'ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded' function instead of `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(whatfunction, "init.js");`, my jquery-based css edits fail.

Comment: they fail in what way?

Comment: The javascript functions never fire (sorry, I should've said that...)

Comment: now you're talking about jquery.  that's a separate issue altogether. I'd recommend asking a new question about integrating the CSOM with jquery.

Comment: Okay. I guess it's my fault for considering jquery to be javascript.  However, I will try out your suggestions with plain javascript, and I'll mark my answer after I get them working.  I am sure you have the answer, but I can't really mark it until I know it will work for me, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Well, I got the function to fire, but am having problems getting info from the page. Please see my last comment under my question.