# How to load multiple item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, list-item

I'm using SharePoint 2010.
I'm trying to load mutliple selected item from a view in a ribbon on a custom list.
I can have the selecteditems but when i try to display a value for an item, i've an exception

> undefined is not a function

I found this post and still not working: [Cannot get field value of list item through JavaScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29295/cannot-get-field-value-of-list-item-through-javascript)

```
    javascript:   
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var items = [];
var lists = web.get_lists();
var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
var list = lists.getById(listId);
var viewcollection = list.get_views();
var view = list.get_views().getByTitle("All Items");
var vf = [];
var viewFields = view.get_viewFields();
context.load(viewFields);
context.load(viewFields);
context.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);
function OnSuccess(){
    alert("viewfield ok");
    var e = viewFields.getEnumerator();
    while (e.moveNext()) {
        var fieldName = e.get_current();
        vf.push(fieldName);
        var listField = vf.join();
    }
    alert(listField);
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(); 
    alert("debut");

    for (var i in selectedItems) {
        var id = selectedItems[i].id;
        alert(id);
        var item = list.getItemById(id);
        items.push(item);
        context.load(item, "LinkTitle");
    }
    context.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccessLoadItem,OnFailureLoadItem);
    function OnSuccessLoadItem(){
        for (var it in items) {
            //exception is throwed here and the column exist
            alert("success="+it.get_item("LinkTitle"));
        }
    }
    function OnFailureLoadItem(){
        alert("zut");
    }
}
function OnFailure(){
    alert("failure viewfields");
}
```

-Correction:

i changed the loop for displaying item

```
for(var cpt=0;cpt<items.length;cpt++){
            alert("success="+items[cpt].get_item("LinkTitle"));

        }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What you mean by not working?

Comment: i mean that throws undefined exception and i cannot have the value for my items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var items = [];
var lists = web.get_lists();
var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
var list = lists.getById(listId);
for (var i in selectedItems) {
    var id = selectedItems[i].id;
    var item = list.getItemById(id);
    items.push(item);
    context.load(item, "Include(Title)"); //Add other field you want to include by separated with commad
}
context.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);
function OnSuccess(){
    alert("viewfield ok");
    for (var item in items) {
        alert(item.get_item("Title"));
        //alert(item.get_item("FieldInternalName");
    }
}
function OnFailure(sender, args) {
  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: i added include but still have the same error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: uncaught referenceError: Include is not defined

Comment: sorry i wrote wrong what you did but now the executequery fail and i enter in the function onfailure

Comment: OnFailure use this to find the exact error `alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());` - Check updated answer

Comment: Here is the complete error -invalid request : undefined

Answer (score 0):

If error is about `Include`  try replacing `context.load(item, "Include(Title)")` with  `context.load(item, 'Include(Title)')`

Comment: it doesn't work the executequery fails

Answer (score 0):

The came from the loop after loaded items. I changed by a classic loop and now it's working

```
           function OnSuccessLoadItem(){
        for(var cpt=0;cpt<items.length;cpt++){
            alert("success="+items[cpt].get_item(vf[1]));
        }
    }
```